# Text running out of fbox

Tags: pdftex, boxes, minipage, adjustbox, cryptocode

I have the following piece of Latex code. I want the text to be inside that box but it is running outside. Can someone please help?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage [
  n,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{changepage}
    \begin{figure}
    
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \procedure[linenumbering]{${\bf Exp}_{{\sf IB-MSS}}^{uf-cma}(\adv)$}{%
      ({\sf pp},MSK) \gets {\sf Setup}(\eta); {\sf MIdLst}\gets \emptyset ; {\sf CIdLst} \gets \emptyset   \\
      \text{Run } \adv({\sf pp}), \text{and handle } \adv \text{’s key derivation and signature queries as follows:}  \\
      \text{On a key derivation query on identity ${\sf Id}$, add ${\sf Id}$ to ${\sf CIdLst}$, run ${\sf KeyGen}$ on input $(MSK, {\sf Id})$ and return ${\sf sk_{Id}}$ to $\adv$}\\
    \text{On a signing query on pair $({\sf msg, Id})$, add ${\sf (msg, Id)}$ to ${\sf MIdLst}$}\\
     \text{run ${\sf Sign}$ protocol on behalf of identity ${\sf Id}$ on message ${\sf msg}$ forwarding messages to and from $\adv$.}\\
     \text{When $\adv$ halts, parse its output as ${\sf (msg}, IdSet, \sigma)$} \\ 
     \text{If ${\sf Verify}({\sf pp, msg},IdSet, \sigma )=1 \wedge (\exists;\ {\sf Id}\in IdSet$  such that $({\sf Id}\notin {\sf CIdLst}) \wedge (({\sf msg, Id})\notin {\sf MIdLst})) $ then return $1$, otherwise return $0$.}
      }\end{minipage}}
    
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that math mode does not automatically add linebreaks. One option when using cryptocode in math mode would be to use manual linebreaks, possibly together with `\pcskipln` as follows

```
\procedure[linenumbering]{Header}{%
  \text{first line}   \\
  \text{some long}  \pcskipln\\
  \text{line} \\
  \text{some long}  \pcskipln\\
  \text{line} 
}
```

This produces something along the following lines.

[image: Manual linebreak example]

Since in your case, the math part is actually small compared to text I would, however, suggest to use cryptocode in text mode using the `mode=text` option together with `width`. Following is your example adjusted to a width of 8cm.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage [
  n,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   
 \begin{pchstack}[center]
    \fbox{\procedure[linenumbering,width=8cm,mode=text]{${\bf Exp}_{{\sf IB-MSS}}^{uf-cma}(\adv)$}{%
      $({\sf pp},MSK) \gets {\sf Setup}(\eta); {\sf MIdLst}\gets \emptyset ; {\sf CIdLst} \gets \emptyset$   \\
      Run $\adv({\sf pp})$, and handle $\adv$’s key derivation and signature queries as follows:  \\
      On a key derivation query on identity ${\sf Id}$, add ${\sf Id}$ to ${\sf CIdLst}$, run ${\sf KeyGen}$ on input $(MSK, {\sf Id})$ and return ${\sf sk_{Id}}$ to $\adv$\\
    On a signing query on pair $({\sf msg, Id})$, add ${\sf (msg, Id)}$ to ${\sf MIdLst}$\\
     run ${\sf Sign}$ protocol on behalf of identity ${\sf Id}$ on message ${\sf msg}$ forwarding messages to and from $\adv$.\\
     When $\adv$ halts, parse its output as ${\sf (msg}, IdSet, \sigma)$ \\ 
     If ${\sf Verify}({\sf pp, msg},IdSet, \sigma )=1 \wedge (\exists;\ {\sf Id}\in IdSet$  such that $({\sf Id}\notin {\sf CIdLst}) \wedge (({\sf msg, Id})\notin {\sf MIdLst})) $ then return $1$, otherwise return $0$.
      }}
      \end{pchstack}
\end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Example with text mode]

As a side note: you may want to have a look at `\createprocedureblock` for creating a convenience command for centered and boxed pseudocode sections.